# Rails3 app tries to connect with incorrect db user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a basic rails3 app that I am deploying on site5. I have installed all the required gems, using bundler, and when I try to run rake db:migrate or rake db:schema:load, I get:

```
# rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
(in /home/xxx/rails/costfinder)
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My config/database.yml has:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: xxx_costfinder_production
  user: ****
  password: ******
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I have no idea why rails is trying to connect as root. Any suggestions? My experience is with rails2, this is my first stab at a rails3 app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aieeee, it's `username`, not `user`